# Automatically update generated fish scripts (completions, etc)

Tags: fish

Let's say I have a completions scripts generated by `gh completion -s fish` and saved to an appropriate location. The question is: how do I update the script automatically on `gh` updates? Is there a plugin or should I do some scripting?

Answer (score 3):

If `gh completion -s fish` is fast, you can just run it as the script that loads completions. Create a `~/.config/fish/completions/gh.fish` with the following contents:

```
gh completion -s fish | source
```

Then it will be run on first load in each shell instance, though it won't reload during the lifetime of that instance.

Alternatively, you could set up a scheduled task (eg cron) or trigger depending on the operating system you are using.